# Sympy notation for matrix multiplication

Tags: sympy

In numpy it is standard to define matrices and dot product as shown below

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
b = np.array([[7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14], [15, 16, 17, 18]])
print(a.shape)
print(b.shape)
print(a.dot(b).shape)
```

which outputs as expected:

```
(2, 3)
(3, 4)
(2, 4)
```

But to my surprise the following fails in sympy

```
import sympy as sp
a = sp.Matrix([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
b = sp.Matrix([[7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14], [15, 16, 17, 18]])
print(a.shape)
print(b.shape)
print(a.dot(b).shape)
```

which outputs

```
(2, 3)
(3, 4)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ShapeError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-50c934c7fbaf> in <module>()
      4 print(a.shape)
      5 print(b.shape)
----> 6 print(a.dot(b).shape)

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/matrices/matrices.py in dot(self, b)
   2389                 mat = mat.T
   2390                 b = b.T
-> 2391             prod = flatten((mat * b).tolist())
   2392             if len(prod) == 1:
   2393                 return prod[0]

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/core/decorators.py in binary_op_wrapper(self, other)
    130                     else:
    131                         return f(self)
--> 132             return func(self, other)
    133         return binary_op_wrapper
    134     return priority_decorator

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/matrices/common.py in __mul__(self, other)
   2006             if self.shape[1] != other.shape[0]:
   2007                 raise ShapeError("Matrix size mismatch: %s * %s." % (
-> 2008                     self.shape, other.shape))
   2009 
   2010         # honest sympy matrices defer to their class's routine

ShapeError: Matrix size mismatch: (3, 2) * (4, 3).
```

This is confusing for me!

Why the inconsistency between numpy and sympy?

Why can't I find a warning of this behaviour in sympy's documentation?

How can I correctly compute the dot product of two matrices in sympy?

May I suggest that the documentation of sympy has an entry on the differences of syntax between numpy and sympy. (I would gladly contribute but I have no idea on those differences)

Comment: I don't think there is much similarity between NumPy syntax and SymPy syntax. The differences would be everything so one may as well read the docs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Matrix product in SymPy is computed as `a*b`.

The [method `dot` in SymPy](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/matrices/matrices.html#sympy.matrices.matrices.MatrixBase.dot) is meant to allow computing dot products of two matrices that represent vectors, for example:

```
>>> sp.Matrix([1, 2]).dot(sp.Matrix([3, 4]))
11
```

is the dot product of two column-vectors.  There is a transpose involved in this.

> Return the dot product of Matrix self and b relaxing the condition of compatible dimensions: if either the number of rows or columns are the same as the length of b then the dot product is returned. If self is a row or column vector, a scalar is returned. Otherwise, a list of results is returned (and in that case the number of columns in self must match the length of b).

Comment: Output if you use this in a current SymPy Version:

SymPyDeprecationWarning: 

Dot product of non row/column vectors has been deprecated since SymPy
1.2. Use * to take matrix products instead. See
https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/13815 for more info.

  useinstead="* to take matrix products").warn()

Answer (score 7):

I'll post here a reply from the developers of SymPy on Github:

> As a general rule, in NumPy, all operations vectorize over arrays. In
>   SymPy, operations do their usual mathematical meaning. This means that
>   SymPy is generally more restrictive to keeping things mathematically
>   "pure".
>
> The most obvious one first: in NumPy, everything is numeric. Functions take a number or array of numbers and produce a number or
>   array of numbers. In SymPy, everything is symbolic. Expressions can
>   use symbolic variables that remain unevaluated by default. For
>   example, np.exp(np.pi) produces a number, but sympy.exp(sympy.pi)
>   produces an unevaluated expression (which can be evaluated to a number
>   with sympy.exp(sympy.pi).evalf()).
>
> In general, SymPy functions will not work on NumPy arrays and NumPy functions will not work on SymPy expressions. If you want to mix
>   SymPy and NumPy, it is recommended to use lambdify (start with a SymPy
>   expression using only SymPy functions, then use lambdify to convert it
>   to an equivalent NumPy function, and use that on NumPy arrays with
>   NumPy numeric types). I've discussed this on StackOverflow many times.
>
> '*' is matrix multiplication. Note that @ (Python 3.5+) does matrix multiplication in both NumPy and SymPy.
>
> sympy.Matrix is always rank 2. NumPy arrays can be any rank. Note that dot/@ in NumPy work on any rank array. There is some weird
>   behavior on rank 1 arrays (it basically treats them as both column or
>   row vectors, depending on the context).
>
> Calling a mathematical function on a matrix in SymPy, if it works, performs the analytic matrix valuation of that function. For example,
>   exp(M) computes the matrix exponential. Matrix.applyfunc can be used
>   to apply functions elementwise. In NumPy, exp(A) takes the exponential
>   of each element of A (use scipy.linalg.expm to take a matrix
>   exponential of a NumPy array).
>
> np.dot does matrix multiplication. In SymPy, dot does a dot product (takes two 1xn or nx1 matrices and produces a scalar).
>   sympy.dot errors (actually currently in master gives a deprecation
>   warning) if the arguments are not 1xn.
>
> A 1x1 matrix is not considered the same thing as a scalar in SymPy. 1 + Matrix([[1]]) is an error.